# server removes duplicate slashes

Tags: php, url-rewriting

server removes duplicate slashes from url,
if i try to get http://mysite.com/a//b/

with .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?r=$1 [L]
```

string that comes to php script is "a/b/" but expected "a//b/"
how can i disable removing slashes from url?

Comment: Also, you should not design applications to expect duplicate slashes. They may be filtered out by the browser and cause ambiguities in site layout.

Comment: string parsed then as key/value/key/value so removing slashes causing problems

Comment: I had the same "problem" and now I am just sending URLs with null as word if there is no value (e.g. "/key1/null/key2/value2/"). I never had any problem since that and I never had any part in any application where I need to send "null" as real value (i.e. string).

Comment: 100% agree with eisberg. This is what you should do to fix it - don't try double slashes. They may be cleaned up somewhere, as you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talkin about the Path part of an URL/URI here. A path is by definition something like

> path/to/file

- there is no such thing as a "//", since that's an invalid.

See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt section 3.3. HTTP:

> Within the  and  components, "/", ";", "?" are
>   reserved.  The "/" character may be used within HTTP to designate a
>   hierarchical structure.

There are no paths with a//b.